# strlen() ломает исходный строковый литерал

Tags: c++, c

В общем столкнулся с таким непонятным багом. Есть функция, которая упаковывает исходное сообщение в некий пакет. Для этого она находит длину исходного сообщения. и вот тут то вызывается `strlen(message);`. message - const char* из аргумента функции. до вызова strlen это обычная строка, после вызова однако она коверкается до неузнаваемости. Собирал g++ и clang++ оба с -O0 -g. однако повторить в минимальном варианте вне кода самой программы не получается.

Что тут вообще может случиться, что меняется строковый литерал?

```
это вызывается из конструктора одного класса:
{
const char* reuest = scom::create_auth_request("User");
socket->send(request);
}


const char* scom::create_auth_request(const char* name)
{
  const char* result;
  int len;

  len = strlen(name);
  char buff[1 + len];
  sprintf(buff, "%01d%s", AUTH_REQUEST, name); /* AUTH_REQUEST = 0 */
  result = buff;
  return result;
}



void scom::ClientSocket::send(int connection, const char* message)
{
  unsigned int total = 0;
  /* здесь message = "0User" */
  unsigned int len = strlen(message);
  /* здесь message уже "h\364\n\br" */


  /* остальное уже в принципе не важно */
  /*
  if(len > 1024)
    throw scom::Exception();

  unsigned int bytesleft = len + 2;
  unsigned int n;

  char to_send[len + 2];
  memset(to_send, 0, len + 2);

  uint16_t nlen = htons(len);
  to_send[0] = nlen>>8;
  to_send[1] = nlen;

  strcpy(to_send+2, message);

  while(total < len + 2)
  {
    n = ::send(connection, to_send+total, bytesleft, 0);
    if(n == -1)
      break;
    total += n;
    bytesleft -= n;
  }

  if(n == -1)
    throw scom::Send();
}
*/
```

Comment: есть много вариантов. Но думаю, что в данном случае нужно смотреть, как именно эта функция вызывается. Если в Вашем приложении несколько тредов или сам message получается с другой функции - то заданное поведение получить легко.

Comment: потоков и правда несколько, однако эта функция, и функция возвращающая message, находятся в одном потоке и вызываются последовательно

Comment: для начала покажите функцию, которая возвращает message и как вызывается в результате send.

Comment: добавлю, что create_auth_request() вызывается один раз за все время существования объекта. при этом message меняется точно после выполнения strlen(), и в результате передается абракадабра

Answer (score 3, accepted):

посмотрел на `scom::create_auth_request` - там возвращается указатель на локальный буфер. По выходу с функции он конечно в памяти остается и даже данные по нему живые, но когда вызывается следующая функция, она перетирает стек своими переменными - она же не знает о том, что там остались данные. Это абсолютно совпадает с наблюдаемым поведением. В Вашем случае этот буфер перетирает собственно `strlen`.

Как можно ещё проверить, что это именно так. Перепишите функцию отправки так

```
void scom::ClientSocket::send(int connection, const char* message)
{
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  int z = 0;
  unsigned int total = 0;
  /* здесь message = "0User" */
```

нужно именно как минимум 8 байт, потому что в create_auth_request буфер находиться как минимум с 9 байта. Но компилятор может это дело все переставить.

Как это пофиксить. Первый способ - передать буфер `buff` как параметр функции и хранить его  вызывающей программе. Второй способ - выделить память явно через malloc. Третий способ - писать все таки на с++  и использовать `std::string` вместо `char*`.

B.T.W. - Вы похоже используете [VLA](https://habrahabr.ru/post/195148/) - а это gcc специфик.

Comment: @Feanor1397,  простейший фикс (с выделением памяти) это написать `return strdup(result);`

Comment: И правда, я же возвращаю указатель на локальный массив... а vla штука странная, вроде для gcc, а clang компилит точно так же

Comment: @Feanor1397, VLA правильная вещь, поэтому все (у кого голова есть?) ее рано или поздно сделают

Comment: VLA по стандарту только для си кода. Но gcc (а вместе с ним и с clang)  расширяют. Студия в плюсовом коде это не поддерживает.  В сишном коде я не проверял.

Comment: Я тут оставлю комментарий про valgrind, отладчик (плюс собсвенные глязья) etc...

Comment: VLA поддерживался борландами. Это, не то что атавизм, но очень странная конструкция в свете идеологии С++, более уместная в CLI, это  приводит к очень низкому качеству обучения студентов, которые привыкают к написанию кода с использованием VLA. Уж лучше бы С++ реализовал создание многомерных массивов через new.